# Sorting Multiple Columns in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a hard time trying to sort my columns. Should seem like an easy fix but I keep getting stuck. My columns are set up so that when it first populates, Column A might have values in row 3 6 9 12, Column B might have values in 1 2 3 4 and C might have values in 10 20 and 30. I'm trying to go from Column A to Column C and recursively sorting it alphabetically. I have hardcoded as a sub but everytime it gets to a column without values it ends the the program entirely. This is what I have so far

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("G1:G3000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With


ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("H1:H3000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With


ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("I1:I3000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With


ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("J1:J3000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

I'm calling the function on two sheets. On sheet 1 it has values up to J but on sheet 2 it only has values up to I and it gets stuck giving me an error on Sheet 2 because theres nothing on J. How couple I incorporate a for loop and how would my program know if there is/is not a value in the next column?

```
       Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D    Column E
Row 1   Bread       Fruit
Row 2   Apple        OJ         Coffee  
Row 3   Banana      Bread       Lotion      Water
Row 4   Soda            
Row 5   Fruit       Coke        
Row 6   Coffee      Tea
```

Comment: Didn't understand your question completely, but if you want a dynamic range, you can try something like `range(range("J1"),range("J1")).end(xldown)`

Comment: Do you mean to sort each column independently from each other? You may want to find last row in a column and if it equals 1 then you have nothing in the column to sort (if  Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) > 1 then sort)

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data (what it looks like to start) and expected results (what you want it to look like after).  Right now it's kind of unclear.

Comment: @tigeravatar So as you can see in the sample data i've included, I want to sort first column, then second... etc. But I've hardcoded it to the certain columns. In my example, this would be Sheet2 and then my program would end because it's hardcoded and theres nothing in Column 5

Comment: @Alfred I have posted a solution which I think will work for you, give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, something like this might work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        Select Case ws.Name
            Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2"
                For i = ws.Columns("A").Column To ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, i), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp))
                        If .Cells.Count > 1 Then
                            .Sort .Cells, xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
                        End If
                    End With
                Next i
        End Select
    Next ws

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

If your data doesn't actually have headers, try this instead:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rLast As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        Select Case ws.Name
            Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2"
                On Error Resume Next
                Set rLast = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not rLast Is Nothing Then
                    For i = ws.Columns("A").Column To rLast.Column
                        With ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, i), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp))
                            If .Cells.Count > 1 Then .Sort .Cells, xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
                        End With
                    Next i
                End If
        End Select
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: It worked, but only until the column that has values but nothing in row 1. So for example on my sample I've provided, it'll sort column 1 but stop at the next column because nothing is in (B,1)

Comment: @Alfred Your provided code specifies that you have headers `.Header = xlYes`.  Headers means you have something in row 1.  Is that not the case with your actual data?

Comment: @Alfred I have added a second option if your data doesn't actually have headers

Comment: Yes I have headers

Comment: @Alfred alright, are your headers not in row 1?  If you have headers, the first option should work for you if your column headers are in row 1.

Comment: Does it matter if my cells are blank in the headers? My autofilter is still counting those blank cells

Comment: @Alfred A blank cell is not a header.  Use the second option in that case.  The reason your autofilter is counting the blank cells is because you hard-coded the ranges.

Comment: Say that Column 1 and 2 have headers, but Column 3 and 4 are blank. I just want to sort 3 and 4. Would I go about the same way using option 2?

Comment: @Alfred Have you tried the second option yet? You should try it.

Comment: Change the `"A"` in this line: `For i = ws.Columns("A").Column To rLast.Column` to whatever column letter you want to start on.

Comment: @DisplayName I know, I just find it much easier to tell people how to set the column they want to start from with the proposed syntax.  Especially if it's a weird column, like "EZ" or something.

Comment: @tigeravatar How would i change it so that when i sort one cell in a column, it sorts the entire row? like if i moved apple to the top of column A, then coffee also moves to the top of column C

Comment: @Alfred If you do this, you'll have blank cells in your data still because you won't be sorting columns individually anymore.  Is that the intent?  Also, that request is fundamentally different from your original goal stated in the question.  This might be better suited as a brand new question.

Comment: @tigeravatar Yes exactly. I'm sorry this is one of my first times on stack overflow. Sometimes I don't exactly know if I'm relaying the exact things I'm asking. I've edited the dated to show exactly how the data would be in my set. So theres not actually missing data between columns. It would just be sorting left to right as row blocks. and the final product would be Row 3,2,5,1,6,4